# How to use the plugin with phonegap build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

How to use the plugin with phonegap build 
I have tried to attach the plugin as below the both the code in my config file

```
<gap:plugin name="de.cyberkatze.phonegap.plugin.PdfViewer" source="https://github.com/cyberkatze/pdfViewer">

<gap:plugin name="de.cyberkatze.phonegap.plugin.PdfViewer" source="plugins.cordova.io">
```

but its not working

so kindly tell how to fix it to attach the plugin with phonegap build

Comment: What kind of error do you receive? not working is the most generic problem and is not simple to find the cause.

Comment: Use command line tools to install the plugins

Comment: that plugin isn't available in phonegap build or plugins.cordova.io. fork it and submit it yourself

Answer (score 0):

To complete what @jcesarmobile answered in the comments, you can use in phonegap build only plugins that have passed submission.

All the available plugins are listed in this page : https://build.phonegap.com/plugins

If you don't find a plugin here, it either hasn't been submited for validation, or hasn't been aproved yet. In that case you can try to submit it yourself (in some case submission can be quite long).

Edit:

Only paid phonegap users can submit plugins on the phonegap build repository. If that's not your case you can use cordova's plugin repository : http://plugins.cordova.io/

To use a plugin from cordova.io instead of from phonegap, use source="plugins.cordova.io" in the `<plugin>`tag : `<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.example" source="plugins.cordova.io" />`

There doesn't seem to be any pdf viewer there either, but you can try to submit the plugin to plugins.cordova.io.